# MySQL select field from table with criteria

Tags: mysql, select, wordpress

My MySQL skills are poor so sorry for posting such an easy question!
I've got a table with one row where coupon_code = discountmail . I now want to select that row and get the value of value. Why doesn't this work?

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query(
"
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wpsc_coupon_codes WHERE coupon_code = 'discountmail'
"
);
$likeCoupon = $wpdb->get_row('query', output_type, row_offset);
echo $likeCoupon['value'];
```

Cheers!

EDIT: changed the code but it's still outputting nothing.

Comment: what are the table fields.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it differently, according to the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) you first need to prepare the query and then get the variable like so:

```
<?php
$wpdb->query(
    "
    SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wpsc_coupon_codes WHERE coupon_code = 'discountmail'
    "
);

$wpdb->get_row('query', output_type, row_offset);
?>
```

There after you can access the value `$likeCoupon['value'];`.

Comment: Hi Anriëtte, I've edited my code but it seems like it's still not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: You correctly assigned your row to `$likeCoupon`, but you need to specify the `output_type` as `ARRAY_A` like so `$likeCoupon = $wpdb->get_row('query', ARRAY_A);`

Comment: And if it still doesn't work change it to this: `$likeCoupon = $wpdb->get_row('SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wpsc_coupon_codes WHERE coupon_code = \'discountmail\'', ARRAY_A);`

Comment: Tip: don't change your original code in your post, append **edits://** only, don't change original post code.